# Looking for generalization of projective model structure

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories

If $\mathcal{M}$ is a cofibrantly generated model category and $\mathcal{C}$ is a small category, then we can give $\mathcal{M}^\mathcal{C}$ the projective model structure, in which weak equivalences and fibrations are transformations that are such on each object of $\mathcal{C}$. I recall seeing a generalization in which we take a subset $D$ of objects of $\mathcal{C}$ and say that a transformation $f$ is a weak equivalence or fibration if $f(d)$ is one *for every $d\in D$* (and require nothing at the other objects). Am I remembering correctly that this works in this generality, and does anyone have a reference for where this is written down? I'd like to use this but see no need to reinvent the wheel if I can just refer to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This model structure has appeared explicitly in the paper by Paul Balmer and Michel Matthey "[Codescent theory I: Foundations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864104001828?via%3Dihub)". Theorem 3.5 establishes the existence of, what the authors called, the relative model structure.

But the ideas behind this model structure go back to Dwyer-Kan concept of an *orbit* introduced in the paper "[Singular functors and realization functors](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/1385725884900167)". If you choose the set of orbits to be the representable functors $hom_{\mathcal{C}}(d,-)$ for all $d\in \mathcal{D}$, then this set of orbits defines the same $\mathcal{D}$-relative model structure on the category of $\mathcal{C}$-indexed diagrams.

Comment: Thanks! The Balmer-Matthey reference gives it quite explicitly. I should have remembered Dwyer-Kan as well, given that the context I'm interested in comes from equivariant homology.

Answer (score 4):

We can apply the Kan transfer theorem (Theorem 11.3.2 in Hirschhorn)
to the right adjoint functor U: M^C→M^D, where M^D is equipped with the projective model structure.
Its left adjoint F sends representable functors y(X) on D
to the corresponding representable functors y(X) on C.
The conditions in the theorem boil down to verifying that U takes relative
F(y(X)⊗J)-complexes to weak equivalences (J denotes a set of generating
acyclic cofibrations of M), where X∈D.

However, F(y_D(X)⊗J)=y_C(X)⊗J is a subclass of projective acylic cofibrations
(which are generated by y_C(X)⊗J for all X∈C),
and every projective acyclic cofibration is an objectwise weak equivalence,
which completes the proof.

Answer (score 4):

You might be thinking of the paper ["On Modified Reedy and Modified Projective Model Structures" by Mark Johnson](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/24/8/24-08.pdf). It does exactly what you asked in your question, in Proposition 6.4. Funny you should mention reinventing the wheel; I reproved this result a few years ago in a [mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/104423/11540), before I knew about Mark's paper.

Comment: Thanks. I'm starting to think this is a "folklore" result that gets rediscovered and republished periodically (in various forms). I probably first saw it in someone's talk about model structures on diagrams of fixed points in equivariant homotopy theory, but at the moment I don't remember who or when.